# Somehow access Android body sensor from a web page?

Tags: javascript, android, html, hardware

I'd like to create a web page which can access a body sensor on an Android tablet (to detect if someone is standing in front of the tablet).

I'd love to do this with a web page (an actual web page, not a PhoneGap/Cordova app). I've seen demos of accessing the webcam from a web page via HTML5/JS in Opera. I'd love to do the same with a body sensor.

Is there ANY way to achieve this? I'm okay with using a browser plugin if necessary or even a customed Android browser (that supports HTML5/CSS3).

Alternatively, is this even possible with PhoneGap/Cordova?

Comment: Do you have an example of any device that has a "body sensor"? The proximity sensor is just based on light, typically reaching the front-facing camera, and so is designed to detect the existence of a cheek, nothing more. It will not "determine if someone is standing in front of the tablet".

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to do? I would assume that someone is holding the tablet if they just navigated to your webpage...

Comment: @CommonsWare The device I have is custom and has something similar to a proximity sensor but can detect things further away. I don't know if it is officially called a body sensor...I'm still finding documentation.

Comment: @Larry The tablet will sit on a table and play a video when someone is standing there.

Comment: Then you will need to ask the manufacturer of the device how to do what it is that you want. Nobody else can help you.

Comment: Okay, so, let's think more generally. Basically I am asking if there is a way, without PhoneGap or similar, to interface with hardware via a web page.  In theory, could I write a browser plugin to provide additional JavaScript API? Some other way? Let's pretend we are attempting to utilize the accelerometer.