# How can I interface with an infrared sensor on Android?

Tags: android, hardware, sensors, infrared

I have an Android device which came with the following infrared sensor connected: [http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/B007XQRKD4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007XQRKD4)

I'd like to interface with this in an Android app I'm writing...I'd like some kind of callback to be called when the sensor detects something.

What do I need to do to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to talk to the manufacturer of the device and ask the manufacturer your questions.

- Only the manufacturer will know what "connected" means (for some manufacturers, "connected" means "attached via duct tape")
- Only the manufacturer will know what Android-compatible drivers, if any, they put on the device that pertain to this piece of hardware
- Only the manufacturer can tell you what programming options there are for that piece of hardware, given how they connected it and the drivers that they supplied

Note that this is also what I recommended that you do when [you asked a related question on this yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20864600/115145).